# typedef function usage in C

Tags: c++, c, rsa

I'm trying to call the following function but I cannot figure out how to fill in the third parameter.

```
RSA* PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(FILE *fp, RSA **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
```

Looking up pem_password_cb I find:

```
typedef int pem_password_cb(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *userdata);
```

I understand typedefs with function pointers, but this doesn't appear to be a function pointer. Can anyone help me with an example of what goes in the third parameter? I don't have access to the implementation of pem_password_cb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right: this is a typedef to a function type, not to a pointer. But the function `PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey` receives a pointer to it: `pem_password_cb *cb`.

The usage is just like any other function pointer:

```
int some_func(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *userdata) {
    return 0;
}

PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(NULL, NULL, some_func, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Your function definition is like this. */

int my_pem_password_cb_fun(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *userdata)
{
    /* your stuff */
}
```

You pass my_pem_password_cb_fun as 3rd parameter.

pem_password_cb is just a typedef and it is not implementation. You need to implement a function [my_pem_password_cb_fun()] that takes parameters as given in typedef.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typedef for a function.

But note that the argument, `pem_password_cb *cb` is a pointer. So the argument really is a function pointer.

So you just need to implement a function that matches the `int pem_password_cb(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *userdata);` signature.